# Show that a finite set $B = \left\{1, x, x^2 \right\}$ is an orthonormal system

Tags: orthogonality, orthonormal

> Show that a finite set $B = \left\{1, x, x^2 \right\}$ is an orthonormal system with respect to the inner product $$\left \langle f, g \right \rangle = \int _{-1}^1\:f\left(t\right)\cdot g\left(t\right) \,\rm{d}t$$ for any $f, g \in L^2 \left[-1, 1 \right]$. Hint: evaluate $\left \langle 1, x \right \rangle, \left \langle 1, x^2 \right \rangle, \left \langle x, x^2 \right \rangle$.

---

As far as I'm concerned, these are the indicators for orthogonality (if they're all zero then the set is orthogonal). My results are consecutively $2x$, $2x^2$, and $2x^3$.

I don't understand - they do equal zero only if $x = 0$. Does that mean that the set is not orthogonal - and therefore cannot be orthonormal? How do I proceed with this problem?

Comment: You should be getting _scalars_ as the values of the inner product, not other polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{a}^b f(x)\,dx$ is not a function of $x$, but a *number* (like, $37$, $92$, $\pi$...). Said number is not to be confused with the function $F(t)= \int_c^t f(x)\,dx$, although the latter is often useful because $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$ and $F$ may be recovered via the relation $F'=f$ if $f$ is continuous.

As for the other observation, yes, strictly speaking orthogonal means $\langle u,v\rangle$ for all $u\ne v$, whereas orthonormal means orthogonal + $\langle u,u\rangle=1$ for all $u$.

It is worth mentioning that the set $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is not orthogonal, though.

*Added:* Now that I think about it, perhaps you did not realise that $x$ does not stand for some number $x$, but rather for the function $f(x)=x$. Likewise, $x^2$ stands for the function $x\mapsto x^2$.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you, that clears things up. So I am assuming the answer "the set is not orthonormal because it is not orthogonal" would be correct?

Comment: Yes, it would.${}$

Comment: @retiredgoblin None of those vectors have unit norm, either.

Answer (score 0):

I think what they're asking is the following:

$$\langle 1, x \rangle = \int_{-1}^1 1 \cdot x dx = \int_{-1}^1 x dx$$
It can be useful to note that the function is odd in a symetric domain, it implies that the integral is 0 (you can also do the integral and obtain the same result as well)

When the inner product is defined, you should integrate with respect of the variables specified. In this case, $f(t) \to f(x) = 1, x$, or $x^2$.

I hope that my answer is useful!